# Spring RequestParam formatter for Scala.Option

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-mvc

We are using Spring MVC in our Scala application and I would like to figure out how to unwrap Scala `Option`'s so they can be properly converted using `@RequestParam`. I think the solution may have something to do with the [Formatter SPI](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-Formatter-SPI), but I am unsure how to get this to work nicely given that `Option`'s can contain any number of values (which I'd want Spring to handle normally, as if the converted value were not an `Option` at all). In essence, I'd almost want to apply an additional conversion of a value to be `Option` wrapped after normal conversion takes place.

For example, given the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = Array(GET), value = Array("/test"))
def test(@RequestParam("foo") foo: Option[String]): String
```

The url `/test` should result in the `foo` parameter getting a value of `None`, while the url `/test?foo=bar` should result in the `foo` parameter getting a value of `Some("bar")` (`/test?foo` could result in either an empty String, or `None`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to solve this by creating an `AnyRef` to `Option[AnyRef]` converter and adding it to Spring MVC's `ConversionService`:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.{Autowired, Qualifier}
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConditionalGenericConverter
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair
import org.springframework.core.convert.{ConversionService, TypeDescriptor}
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

import scala.collection.convert.WrapAsJava

/**
 * Base functionality for option conversion.
 */
trait OptionConverter extends ConditionalGenericConverter with WrapAsJava {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("mvcConversionService")
  var conversionService: ConversionService = _
}

/**
 * Converts `AnyRef` to `Option[AnyRef]`.
 * See implemented methods for descriptions.
 */
@Component
class AnyRefToOptionConverter extends OptionConverter {
  override def convert(source: Any, sourceType: TypeDescriptor, targetType: TypeDescriptor): AnyRef = {
    Option(source).map(s => conversionService.convert(s, sourceType, new Conversions.GenericTypeDescriptor(targetType)))
  }

  override def getConvertibleTypes: java.util.Set[ConvertiblePair] = Set(
    new ConvertiblePair(classOf[AnyRef], classOf[Option[_]])
  )

  override def matches(sourceType: TypeDescriptor, targetType: TypeDescriptor): Boolean = {
    Option(targetType.getResolvableType).forall(resolvableType =>
      conversionService.canConvert(sourceType, new Conversions.GenericTypeDescriptor(targetType))
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but this solution doesn't work