# Convert java.lang.Boolean to Scala Boolean

Tags: java, scala, refactoring

I am currently working on a Scala application which utilizes Spring-Boot and Swagger to send & receive REST-calls.

Swagger and Spring-Boot are pure Java-projects and have limited compatibility with Scala, but I seem to have found a workaround regarding the problem.

Since Spring-Boot and Swagger are handling requests as Java objects (which needs setters & getters to work), I'll have to treat the request as a Java object and convert the request to later. This is a very **simplified version** of what I did:

---

```
case class ParamsAsJava(includeMovies: java.lang.Boolean = java.lang.Boolean.FALSE, includeTvShows: java.lang.Boolean = java.lang.Boolean.FALSE) {

  def toScala(): Params = {
    Params(
      includeMovies = convertToScala(includeMovies),
      includeTvShows = convertToScala(includeTvShows)
    )
  }

  private def convertToScala(test: java.lang.Boolean): Boolean
  = if (test == null) false else test.booleanValue

}

case class Params(includeMovies: Boolean = false, includeTvShows: Boolean = false)

object Application extends App {

  val test1 = ParamsAsJava(java.lang.Boolean.FALSE, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE).toScala
  val test2 = ParamsAsJava(java.lang.Boolean.TRUE, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE).toScala
  val test3 = ParamsAsJava().toScala
  val test4 = ParamsAsJava(null, null).toScala
  val test5 = ParamsAsJava(null, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE).toScala

  println(s"Test 1 = $test1")
  println(s"Test 2 = $test2")
  println(s"Test 3 = $test3")
  println(s"Test 4 = $test4")
  println(s"Test 5 = $test5")
}
```

---

**OUTPUT**

> Test 1 = Params(false,true)
>
> Test 2 = Params(true,true)
>
> Test 3 = Params(false,false)
>
> Test 4 = Params(false,false)
>
> Test 5 = Params(false,true)

---

**OK... my question is:**

Is there an easier & more readable way of achieving this? 
Do I have to call ParamsAsJava.toScala each time or is there some **awesome**  Scala way of doing this?

Comment: Spring can decode or encode pure scala data classes as well. You simply need to inject `ScalaObjectMapper` that supports scala data classes  in  `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala

Comment: The top-voted answer seems to provide an idiomatic Spring solution, which is focused primarily on Spring, not so much on Scala. Maybe that should be reflected in the tags?

Comment: This challenge is not about the ScalaObjectMapper, nor the JacksonObjectMapper, its about the @RequestParam' from the Swagger API that can't deal with objects being 'null' (I've tried Scala Option, doesnt work). 
The solution provided in my question is purely a workaround that I have made because I couldn't find another solution online. 

I have a Java-background and I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this in Scala **OR** if there is some other magic I haven't found yet. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to write out `java.lang.blah` every time in

   ```
   ParamsAsJava(java.lang.Boolean.FALSE, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE)
   ```

   Just use

   ```
   ParamsAsJava(false, true)
   ```

   instead. Autoboxing hasn't gone anywhere.
2. to get rid of `toScala`, define an implicit conversion in `Params` companion object:

   ```
   object Params {
     implicit def params_j2s(p: ParamsAsJava): Params = p.toScala()
   }
   ```

   now you can write:

   ```
   val test1: Params = ParamsAsJava(true, false)
   ```

   and, of course, if you don't define this variable in vacuum, but pass it to a method instead, the right type will be inferred automatically, and the object will be converted implicitly.
3. No need to use parens `()` in `def toScala()`, the method has no side effects.

Answer (score 3):

By default Spring uses jackson-mapper to decode JSON request body to Java classes and encode Java classes to JSON response.

Alternatively you can tell Spring to use [ScalaObjectMapper](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) which works well for scala data classes.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Then configure Spring to use ScalaObjectMapper in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. Example;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@PropertySource(Array("classpath:config/default.properties"))
@ComponentScan(Array(
  "com.prayagupd"
))
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class MyAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  override def extendMessageConverters(converters: java.util.List[HttpMessageConverter[_]]): Unit = {
    val encodeDecoderOpt = converters.asScala.collectFirst { case p: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter => p }

    val jacksonConverter = encodeDecoderOpt.getOrElse(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
    jacksonConverter.setObjectMapper(Config.objectMapper)

    if (encodeDecoderOpt.isEmpty) // because converters is mutable
       converters.add(jacksonConverter)
  }
}


object Config {

  @Bean
  def objectMapper: ObjectMapper = {
    new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  }.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
}
```

That should be it, now you can use pure scala data classes from Spring endpoint definition. Example

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = Array("*"))
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/"))
class MyController @Autowired()(implicit val jacksonObjectMapper: ObjectMapper) {
  import MyController._

  @Async
  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/talk"), method = Array(RequestMethod.POST), consumes = Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE), produces = Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
  def talk(@RequestBody request: MyRequest): MyResponse = {
       // goes here
   }
}

//expose these in client jar if you want
object MyController {
  final case class MyRequest(includeMovies: Boolean, includeTvShows: Boolean, somethingElse: List[String])

  final case class MyResponse(whatever: String)
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. This is not a request body, but request params. I need to do it this way because the application needs to be compatible with other applications (outside my control). The problem is not with Jackson.. jackson is working great :-) The problem is with Swagger (which I have to use to document the API). 
`Field error in object 'Params' on field 'includeMovies': rejected value [null]; codes [typeMismatch.params.includeMovies]; `

I have tried different approaches and it seems like I have to treat everything as Java-values when they arrive as requestParams in Swagger

Comment: I see. I myself remember using java for request params. I will respond once I get time, let me know if this helps - [Spring RequestParam formatter for Scala.Option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39155809/432903).

Answer (score 2):

I used scala.Boolean [box](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Boolean$.html#box(x:Boolean):Boolean) and [unbox](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Boolean$.html#unbox(x:Object):Boolean) methods.

Comment: This should be the top answer as of 2023.