# How to Convert java.lang.Boolean to scala.Boolean?

Tags: java, scala

**How can a `java.lang.Boolean` be converted to a `scala.Boolean`?**

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581683/convert-java-lang-boolean-to-scala-boolean) which is specific to Spring and Swagger.  My question is more generic and applicable in any circumstances.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Use `Boolean.box` - As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Boolean$.html) is your friend.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you, but `box` is the wrong direction.  That's for scala => java, I want java => scala

Comment: There is `unbox` right below in the docs...

Comment: God, I even looked for it before commenting and still I wrote it wrong... I am a failure. Anyways, should we close this? Or should I add it as an answer? I think this falls close to a typo but not sure what other folks think.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Boolean.unbox`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.9/scala/Boolean$.html#unbox(x:Object):Boolean) method will convert to scala Boolean.

Comment: You can also just type-ascribe: `(new java.lang.Boolean(false)): scala.Boolean` compiles